# How to get /usr/libexec/java_home to filter out the JRE installations?

Tags: java, macos, jvm

I have the following in my `.zshrc` file so I can quickly switch between JDK 8 and JDK 11. However I also have the JRE 8 and JRE 11 installed.

When I run the `java8` alias (which uses the `/usr/libexec/java_home` script), it will default to the JRE instead of the JDK because they're the same version number.

Is it possible to filter out the JRE or to specify the JDK?

```
# java_home
java_version() {
    /usr/libexec/java_home -v $1
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)
    print "Switching JAVA_HOME to $JAVA_HOME"
}
alias java8="java_version 1.8"
alias java11="java_version 11"
export DEFAULT_JAVA_VERSION=1.8
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $DEFAULT_JAVA_VERSION) #default to 8
```

List of JVMs installed:

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    11.0.11 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.11 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK (JRE) 11" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jre/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK (JRE) 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jre/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Edit: the "-v" flag only outputs the path to the version passed on. And the "-V" flag will output all versions detected in the system.

Comment: `/usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep -v JRE` will filter out the JREs

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same output. The "-v" flag also has a different output than the "-V". The lowercase one outputs just the version you pass as a parameter, and the uppercase one displays all of them.

Comment: That's very strange. The only way in which that would have no effect is if the command output were printing to stderr. Can you tell me what happens when you try it like this:  `/usr/libexec/java_home -V 2>&1 | grep -v JRE`